# Update a specific record in Firebase using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

How I can access the whole object where phoneNo = 222 and update its lang and lat

```
  var db = new Firebase("myFB/names");
 names {
    -K7VQBTELD4FQE1HL1U{
       phoneNo: 111,
       long: 126,
       lat: 458
     }

    -K7WJGBTELD4FQ1EHL1U{
       phoneNo: 222,
       long: 547,
       lat: 951
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Firebase query requires an order by function, then you can restrict to a criteria like `equalTo()`.

```
var ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>/names");
var query = ref.orderyByChild('phoneNo').equalTo('222');
```

Then you can create a listener that will retrieve the value. The value will come back as an [DataSnapshot](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot), which contains the associated reference. Using that reference you can process whatever updates you need.

```
query.on('value', function(snap) {
  var obj = snap.val();
  var snapRef = snap.ref();
  snapRef.update({
    lat: 32.332325,
    long: 124.2352352
  });
});
```

**However, you don't need to reed the object to update it.** In your case, you're using a `push-id` as a key for `/names`. Perhaps an easier lookup would be the `phoneNo` key. Then you could do the following:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://my-firebase-app/names/222');
ref.update({
  lat: 32.332325,
  long: 124.2352352
});
```